# New dialog doesn't display radio options properly in the mobile view

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, close-dialog

[image]

The radio button is on its own line instead of being aligned with its label.

Comment: Yes I'm aware the developers' focus is on the responsive mode, but IMO the mobile mode is generally superior, and as yet it has not been deprecated.

Comment: FWIW, the radio button is properly aligned in the mobile view in landscape orientation.